# Regular Expression Help for Date Validation - mm-dd-yyyy - PHP

Tags: php, regex

```
 if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{4}$/', '10-30-2013')){
   echo 'true';
}
else {
   echo 'false';
}
```

This not give me true. I think I'm wrong with `regex`. please tell how to correct this `regex`

Comment: Your date contains `-` not `\-`.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. Could you show more lines from the script?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Doesn't matter, the backslash is ignored in this situation.

Comment: It works fine: http://ideone.com/fS3oGx Common thing to check is the length of value in variable, that actually sits instead of `'10-30-2013'`. It might have white-space that you won't be able to see but for regex it's there.

Comment: Can you try this regex: `/\b[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{4}\b/` ?

Comment: @anubhava why should he?  That'll match any string _containing_ a date string, not any string that _is_ a date string.

Comment: sooo many crappy answers... :(

Comment: Off-topic. Basically, this is _debug my code_ question.

Comment: @Alnitak: By means that was a solution, I just wanted to make sure OP is not getting any trailing whitespace while testing with real strings. (Above code will always print `true`).

Comment: @anubhava Even if s/he is getting whitespace would be hiding problem.

Comment: @Leri: Yes but that whitespace will fail the `preg_match` due to presence of `^ and $`

Comment: @anubhava I know. LOL. What OP really needs is to see if it has whitespace and fix that in the first place.

Comment: @Leri: Yes true that is why it was just a comment not an answer :P

Comment: @Duleep I don't really get why you need regex here.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not using regex at all for this -- date validation with regex is a surprisingly difficult thing to get right, due to the variations possible in the number of days in any given month.

Far better to simply use PHP's `DateTime` class to actually parse it into a date object. This will also validate it; if it doesn't meet the specified format, then it won't parse.

```
$dateObj = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('m-d-Y',$inputString);
```

See PHP manual page for [`CreateFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 1):

You should use dedicate functions to parse date ie.:

```
if (strptime ('10-30-2013'  , 'm-d-Y') !== false) {
  echo 'true'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
  echo 'true'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: nice tautological result there...

Answer (score 0):

Actually as the others confirmed, your regex works fine and returns `true`.

But as you made your code shrunken, I think the input string you're trying to show us isn't **exactly** just a `date` and it's within a string or maybe has trailing spaces!

So using `^` and `$` at your regex will result in failure.